# Editing default Weebly elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, weebly

So I am just experimenting with Weebly, and I am currently using the built-in gallery element to display a series of images. When a user clicks on an image within the gallery, it expands and displays the caption below. 
I am attempting to not just display text within the caption box, but a link and a small thumbnail image which will also be a link. Unfortunately captions only support text.

I know how to create a custom element, but it seems a bit overkill to rewrite the gallery feature just for a couple of small tweaks. So I am just wondering whether I can access the Javascript/jquery of the existing gallery element and just make some slight edits, or whether I can access the element, manifest, and javascript files as reference for creating a custom element.

I know I can view HTML/CSS, but since I am dealing with the caption aspect of the image pop up, the public HTML and CSS files won't cut it.

Edit: I would supply code snippet, but I'm yet to be able to access the code, hence the existence of this question.

Website: http://www.davidmurphyphotography.com/featured-artists.html

All help is appreciated,

Thanks.

Comment: Please provide the link of your website and code snippet in your question

Answer (score 0):

Go to your website on the browser (preferably chrome).
Right click on the gallery element >> inspect.

It should open a sidebar with all your HTML code.

You will find the following code there.

```html
<div id="999708087629570980-gallery" class="imageGallery" style="line-height: 0px; padding: 0; margin: 0">
<div id="999708087629570980-imageContainer0" style="float:left;width:33.28%;margin:0;"><div id="999708087629570980-insideImageContainer0" style="position:relative;margin:20px;padding:0 14px 14px 0"><div class="galleryImageHolder galleryCaptionHover" style="position:relative; width:100%; padding:0 0 75.08%;"><div class="galleryInnerImageHolder"><a href="/uploads/4/1/3/8/4138761/9798060_orig.jpg" rel="lightbox[gallery999708087629570980]" onclick="if (!window.lightboxLoaded) return false" title="Title: &quot;Snowgums&quot;, Artist: Rob Blakers, Medium: Photograph on canvas, 31&quot; X 38&quot; print $645, 48&quot; X 38&quot; print $1100
Rob Blakers, born in 1957, grew up in Canberra, close to the ACT Ranges and the south coast of NSW. He took up bush walking in high school and cross-country skiing during the course of a four-year zoology degree at the Australian National University. This degree culminated in a year long research project into bogong moths and other insect life in the Main Range region of the Kosciuszko National Park in NSW.
Upon completing university in 1980 he travelled to Tasmania for a three week cross country skiing holiday. When the snow failed to materialize, he began to work with the Wilderness Society in the campaign to prevent the damming of the Franklin River. This was an extraordinary time in the lives of many people, and a campaign which was ultimately successful in its aim of protecting much of Tasmania’s southwest wilderness as a World Heritage Area. Today, however, large tracts of wild country remain unprotected and logging, in particular, continues to ravage ancient forests across Tasmania.
Images from Rob’s collection have been used extensively for nature conservation, and in a wide variety of publications including books, posters, cards, calendars and diaries, and in magazines ranging from New Scientist to Outdoor Australia.
Many images on this site were taken using view cameras – a medium format Horseman and a large format Ebony. Nikkor and Schneider lenses ranging from 65mm to 300mm were used. Additional images were made using a Canon 5DMk II digital camera with a range of Canon lenses. Rob currently photographs using an Arca Swiss/Phase One medium format digital system with Rodenstock and Schneider lenses. 
" class="w-fancybox"><img src="/uploads/4/1/3/8/4138761/9798060.jpg" class="galleryImage galleryImageBorder" _width="322" _height="250" style="position:absolute;border-width:1px;padding:6px;width:96.7%;top:0%;left:1.65%"></a></div></div></div></div><div id="999708087629570980-imageContainer1" style="float:left;width:33.28%;margin:0;"><div id="999708087629570980-insideImageContainer1" style="position:relative;margin:20px;padding:0 14px 14px 0"><div class="galleryImageHolder galleryCaptionHover" style="position:relative; width:100%; padding:0 0 75.08%;"><div class="galleryInnerImageHolder"><a href="/uploads/4/1/3/8/4138761/8635906_orig.jpg" rel="lightbox[gallery999708087629570980]" onclick="if (!window.lightboxLoaded) return false" title="Artist: Jason Stephens, Title: &quot;Hello Horseshoe&quot;, Limited Edition 2/30, 1200 X 450mm print, Framed Price AUD $1395" class="w-fancybox"><img src="/uploads/4/1/3/8/4138761/8635906.jpg" class="galleryImage galleryImageBorder" _width="400" _height="154" style="position:absolute;border-width:1px;padding:6px;width:100%;top:24.36%;left:0%"></a></div></div></div></div><div id="999708087629570980-imageContainer2" style="float:left;width:33.28%;margin:0;"><div id="999708087629570980-insideImageContainer2" style="position:relative;margin:20px;padding:0 14px 14px 0"><div class="galleryImageHolder galleryCaptionHover" style="position:relative; width:100%; padding:0 0 75.08%;"><div class="galleryInnerImageHolder"><a href="/uploads/4/1/3/8/4138761/2970504_orig.jpg" rel="lightbox[gallery999708087629570980]" onclick="if (!window.lightboxLoaded) return false" title="Title: &quot;cow n calf&quot;, Artist: Rachel Schubert, Limited Edition 4/30, 30 X 20&quot; print...AUD $ 365
<b>test <\b>" class="w-fancybox"><img src="/uploads/4/1/3/8/4138761/2970504.jpg" class="galleryImage galleryImageBorder" _width="400" _height="266" style="position:absolute;border-width:1px;padding:6px;width:100%;top:5.71%;left:0%"></a></div></div></div></div><div id="999708087629570980-imageContainer3" style="float:left;width:33.28%;margin:0;"><div id="999708087629570980-insideImageContainer3" style="position:relative;margin:20px;padding:0 14px 14px 0"><div class="galleryImageHolder galleryCaptionHover" style="position:relative; width:100%; padding:0 0 75.08%;"><div class="galleryInnerImageHolder"><a href="/uploads/4/1/3/8/4138761/8963927_orig.jpg" rel="lightbox[gallery999708087629570980]" onclick="if (!window.lightboxLoaded) return false" title="Title: &quot;songbird feather&quot;, Artist: Rachel Schubert, Limited Edition 3/30, 30 X 20&quot; print...AUD $ 355" class="w-fancybox"><img src="/uploads/4/1/3/8/4138761/8963927.jpg" class="galleryImage galleryImageBorder" _width="400" _height="601" style="position:absolute;border-width:1px;padding:6px;width:49.97%;top:0%;left:25.02%"></a></div></div></div></div><div id="999708087629570980-imageContainer4" style="float:left;width:33.28%;margin:0;"><div id="999708087629570980-insideImageContainer4" style="position:relative;margin:20px;padding:0 14px 14px 0"><div class="galleryImageHolder galleryCaptionHover" style="position:relative; width:100%; padding:0 0 75.08%;"><div class="galleryInnerImageHolder"><a href="/uploads/4/1/3/8/4138761/8652112_orig.jpg" rel="lightbox[gallery999708087629570980]" onclick="if (!window.lightboxLoaded) return false" title="Title: &quot;Vale of Belvoir&quot;, Artist: Hillary Younger ...30 X 20 print...AUD $ 455" class="w-fancybox"><img src="/uploads/4/1/3/8/4138761/8652112.jpg" class="galleryImage galleryImageBorder" _width="400" _height="265" style="position:absolute;border-width:1px;padding:6px;width:100%;top:5.88%;left:0%"></a></div></div></div></div><div id="999708087629570980-imageContainer5" style="float:left;width:33.28%;margin:0;"><div id="999708087629570980-insideImageContainer5" style="position:relative;margin:20px;padding:0 14px 14px 0"><div class="galleryImageHolder galleryCaptionHover" style="position:relative; width:100%; padding:0 0 75.08%;"><div class="galleryInnerImageHolder"><a href="/uploads/4/1/3/8/4138761/2921277_orig.jpg" rel="lightbox[gallery999708087629570980]" onclick="if (!window.lightboxLoaded) return false" title="Title: &quot;Cradle snow time!&quot;, Artist: Mark Walsh, 30 X 20 print...........AUD $ 465" class="w-fancybox"><img src="/uploads/4/1/3/8/4138761/2921277.jpg" class="galleryImage galleryImageBorder" _width="400" _height="266" style="position:absolute;border-width:1px;padding:6px;width:100%;top:5.71%;left:0%"></a></div></div></div></div><div id="999708087629570980-imageContainer6" style="float:left;width:33.28%;margin:0;"><div id="999708087629570980-insideImageContainer6" style="position:relative;margin:20px;padding:0 14px 14px 0"><div class="galleryImageHolder galleryCaptionHover" style="position:relative; width:100%; padding:0 0 75.08%;"><div class="galleryInnerImageHolder"><a href="/uploads/4/1/3/8/4138761/6224412_orig.jpg" rel="lightbox[gallery999708087629570980]" onclick="if (!window.lightboxLoaded) return false" title="Artist: Rob Mullner, Title: &quot;Meander Panorama&quot;, Framed Price AUD $1375
Print: $965" class="w-fancybox"><img src="/uploads/4/1/3/8/4138761/6224412.jpg" class="galleryImage galleryImageBorder" _width="400" _height="117" style="position:absolute;border-width:1px;padding:6px;width:100%;top:30.52%;left:0%"></a></div></div></div></div><div id="999708087629570980-imageContainer7" style="float:left;width:33.28%;margin:0;"><div id="999708087629570980-insideImageContainer7" style="position:relative;margin:20px;padding:0 14px 14px 0"><div class="galleryImageHolder galleryCaptionHover" style="position:relative; width:100%; padding:0 0 75.08%;"><div class="galleryInnerImageHolder"><a href="/uploads/4/1/3/8/4138761/8533975_orig.jpg" rel="lightbox[gallery999708087629570980]" onclick="if (!window.lightboxLoaded) return false" title="Title: &quot;Cold Cradle 2&quot;, Artist: Mark Walsh ...24 X 16 print...AUD $350" class="w-fancybox"><img src="/uploads/4/1/3/8/4138761/8533975.jpg" class="galleryImage galleryImageBorder" _width="400" _height="266" style="position:absolute;border-width:1px;padding:6px;width:100%;top:5.71%;left:0%"></a></div></div></div></div><div id="999708087629570980-imageContainer8" style="float:left;width:33.28%;margin:0;"><div id="999708087629570980-insideImageContainer8" style="position:relative;margin:20px;padding:0 14px 14px 0"><div class="galleryImageHolder galleryCaptionHover" style="position:relative; width:100%; padding:0 0 75.08%;"><div class="galleryInnerImageHolder"><a href="/uploads/4/1/3/8/4138761/7144717_orig.jpg" rel="lightbox[gallery999708087629570980]" onclick="if (!window.lightboxLoaded) return false" title="Artist: Dean Hohn, Title: &quot;Sunset Beach&quot;, Photograph on rolled aluminium sheet, Price AUD $2750
" class="w-fancybox"><img src="/uploads/4/1/3/8/4138761/7144717.jpg" class="galleryImage galleryImageBorder" _width="400" _height="133" style="position:absolute;border-width:1px;padding:6px;width:100%;top:27.86%;left:0%"></a></div></div></div></div><div id="999708087629570980-imageContainer9" style="float:left;width:33.28%;margin:0;"><div id="999708087629570980-insideImageContainer9" style="position:relative;margin:20px;padding:0 14px 14px 0"><div class="galleryImageHolder galleryCaptionHover" style="position:relative; width:100%; padding:0 0 75.08%;"><div class="galleryInnerImageHolder"><a href="/uploads/4/1/3/8/4138761/7563735_orig.jpg" rel="lightbox[gallery999708087629570980]" onclick="if (!window.lightboxLoaded) return false" title="Title: &quot;the mist&quot;, Artist: Garth Smith ...36 X 12 print...AUD $550" class="w-fancybox"><img src="/uploads/4/1/3/8/4138761/7563735.jpg" class="galleryImage galleryImageBorder" _width="400" _height="160" style="position:absolute;border-width:1px;padding:6px;width:100%;top:23.36%;left:0%"></a></div></div></div></div><div id="999708087629570980-imageContainer10" style="float:left;width:33.28%;margin:0;"><div id="999708087629570980-insideImageContainer10" style="position:relative;margin:20px;padding:0 14px 14px 0"><div class="galleryImageHolder galleryCaptionHover" style="position:relative; width:100%; padding:0 0 75.08%;"><div class="galleryInnerImageHolder"><a href="/uploads/4/1/3/8/4138761/6339275_orig.jpg" rel="lightbox[gallery999708087629570980]" onclick="if (!window.lightboxLoaded) return false" title="Title: &quot;sand ripples&quot;, Artist: Garth Smith ...30 X 20 print...AUD $400" class="w-fancybox"><img src="/uploads/4/1/3/8/4138761/6339275.jpg" class="galleryImage galleryImageBorder" _width="400" _height="265" style="position:absolute;border-width:1px;padding:6px;width:100%;top:5.88%;left:0%"></a></div></div></div></div><div id="999708087629570980-imageContainer11" style="float:left;width:33.28%;margin:0;"><div id="999708087629570980-insideImageContainer11" style="position:relative;margin:20px;padding:0 14px 14px 0"><div class="galleryImageHolder galleryCaptionHover" style="position:relative; width:100%; padding:0 0 75.08%;"><div class="galleryInnerImageHolder"><a href="/uploads/4/1/3/8/4138761/1403796_orig.jpg" rel="lightbox[gallery999708087629570980]" onclick="if (!window.lightboxLoaded) return false" title="Title: &quot;the passage of time&quot;, Artist: Garth Smith ...30 X 20 print...AUD $395" class="w-fancybox"><img src="/uploads/4/1/3/8/4138761/1403796.jpg" class="galleryImage galleryImageBorder" _width="400" _height="600" style="position:absolute;border-width:1px;padding:6px;width:50.05%;top:0%;left:24.97%"></a></div></div></div></div><div id="999708087629570980-imageContainer12" style="float:left;width:33.28%;margin:0;"><div id="999708087629570980-insideImageContainer12" style="position:relative;margin:20px;padding:0 14px 14px 0"><div class="galleryImageHolder galleryCaptionHover" style="position:relative; width:100%; padding:0 0 75.08%;"><div class="galleryInnerImageHolder"><a href="/uploads/4/1/3/8/4138761/1396049_orig.jpg" rel="lightbox[gallery999708087629570980]" onclick="if (!window.lightboxLoaded) return false" title="Title: &quot;everlasting&quot;, Artist: Garth Smith ...30 X 24 print...AUD $425" class="w-fancybox"><img src="/uploads/4/1/3/8/4138761/1396049.jpg" class="galleryImage galleryImageBorder" _width="400" _height="500" style="position:absolute;border-width:1px;padding:6px;width:60.06%;top:0%;left:19.97%"></a></div></div></div></div><div id="999708087629570980-imageContainer13" style="float:left;width:33.28%;margin:0;"><div id="999708087629570980-insideImageContainer13" style="position:relative;margin:20px;padding:0 14px 14px 0"><div class="galleryImageHolder galleryCaptionHover" style="position:relative; width:100%; padding:0 0 75.08%;"><div class="galleryInnerImageHolder"><a href="/uploads/4/1/3/8/4138761/3083567_orig.jpg" rel="lightbox[gallery999708087629570980]" onclick="if (!window.lightboxLoaded) return false" title="Title: &quot;Preminghana&quot;, Artist: Garth Smith ...30 X 20 print...AUD $395" class="w-fancybox"><img src="/uploads/4/1/3/8/4138761/3083567.jpg" class="galleryImage galleryImageBorder" _width="400" _height="265" style="position:absolute;border-width:1px;padding:6px;width:100%;top:5.88%;left:0%"></a></div></div></div></div><div id="999708087629570980-imageContainer14" style="float:left;width:33.28%;margin:0;"><div id="999708087629570980-insideImageContainer14" style="position:relative;margin:20px;padding:0 14px 14px 0"><div class="galleryImageHolder galleryCaptionHover" style="position:relative; width:100%; padding:0 0 75.08%;"><div class="galleryInnerImageHolder"><a href="/uploads/4/1/3/8/4138761/8500474_orig.jpg" rel="lightbox[gallery999708087629570980]" onclick="if (!window.lightboxLoaded) return false" title="Title: &quot;6.46AM&quot;, Artist: Garth Smith ...30 X 20 print...AUD $425" class="w-fancybox"><img src="/uploads/4/1/3/8/4138761/8500474.jpg" class="galleryImage galleryImageBorder" _width="400" _height="602" style="position:absolute;border-width:1px;padding:6px;width:49.88%;top:0%;left:25.06%"></a></div></div></div></div><div id="999708087629570980-imageContainer15" style="float:left;width:33.28%;margin:0;"><div id="999708087629570980-insideImageContainer15" style="position:relative;margin:20px;padding:0 14px 14px 0"><div class="galleryImageHolder galleryCaptionHover" style="position:relative; width:100%; padding:0 0 75.08%;"><div class="galleryInnerImageHolder"><a href="/uploads/4/1/3/8/4138761/1281083_orig.jpg" rel="lightbox[gallery999708087629570980]" onclick="if (!window.lightboxLoaded) return false" title="Title: &quot;serenity&quot;, Artist: Rob Mullner...29 X 20 print...AUD $495" class="w-fancybox"><img src="/uploads/4/1/3/8/4138761/1281083.jpg" class="galleryImage galleryImageBorder" _width="400" _height="229" style="position:absolute;border-width:1px;padding:6px;width:100%;top:11.87%;left:0%"></a></div></div></div></div><div id="999708087629570980-imageContainer16" style="float:left;width:33.28%;margin:0;"><div id="999708087629570980-insideImageContainer16" style="position:relative;margin:20px;padding:0 14px 14px 0"><div class="galleryImageHolder galleryCaptionHover" style="position:relative; width:100%; padding:0 0 75.08%;"><div class="galleryInnerImageHolder"><a href="/uploads/4/1/3/8/4138761/7636977_orig.jpg" rel="lightbox[gallery999708087629570980]" onclick="if (!window.lightboxLoaded) return false" title="Title: &quot;ying and yang&quot;, Artist: Garth Smith ...30 X 20 print...AUD $495" class="w-fancybox"><img src="/uploads/4/1/3/8/4138761/7636977.jpg" class="galleryImage galleryImageBorder" _width="400" _height="266" style="position:absolute;border-width:1px;padding:6px;width:100%;top:5.71%;left:0%"></a></div></div></div></div><div id="999708087629570980-imageContainer17" style="float:left;width:33.28%;margin:0;"><div id="999708087629570980-insideImageContainer17" style="position:relative;margin:20px;padding:0 14px 14px 0"><div class="galleryImageHolder galleryCaptionHover" style="position:relative; width:100%; padding:0 0 75.08%;"><div class="galleryInnerImageHolder"><a href="/uploads/4/1/3/8/4138761/9879220_orig.jpg" rel="lightbox[gallery999708087629570980]" onclick="if (!window.lightboxLoaded) return false" title="Title: &quot;lupinscape&quot;, Artist: Rob Mullner...36 X 20 print...AUD $495" class="w-fancybox"><img src="/uploads/4/1/3/8/4138761/9879220.jpg" class="galleryImage galleryImageBorder" _width="400" _height="193" style="position:absolute;border-width:1px;padding:6px;width:100%;top:17.87%;left:0%"></a></div></div></div></div><div id="999708087629570980-imageContainer18" style="float:left;width:33.28%;margin:0;"><div id="999708087629570980-insideImageContainer18" style="position:relative;margin:20px;padding:0 14px 14px 0"><div class="galleryImageHolder galleryCaptionHover" style="position:relative; width:100%; padding:0 0 75.08%;"><div class="galleryInnerImageHolder"><a href="/uploads/4/1/3/8/4138761/9357429_orig.jpg" rel="lightbox[gallery999708087629570980]" onclick="if (!window.lightboxLoaded) return false" title="Title: &quot;pano Cradle&quot;, Artist: Rob Mullner...Contact me for details" class="w-fancybox"><img src="/uploads/4/1/3/8/4138761/9357429.jpg" class="galleryImage galleryImageBorder" _width="400" _height="149" style="position:absolute;border-width:1px;padding:6px;width:100%;top:25.19%;left:0%"></a></div></div></div></div><div id="999708087629570980-imageContainer19" style="float:left;width:33.28%;margin:0;"><div id="999708087629570980-insideImageContainer19" style="position:relative;margin:20px;padding:0 14px 14px 0"><div class="galleryImageHolder galleryCaptionHover" style="position:relative; width:100%; padding:0 0 75.08%;"><div class="galleryInnerImageHolder"><a href="/uploads/4/1/3/8/4138761/177290_orig.jpg" rel="lightbox[gallery999708087629570980]" onclick="if (!window.lightboxLoaded) return false" title="Title: &quot;pano Mornington&quot;, Artist: Rob Mullner...Contact me for details" class="w-fancybox"><img src="/uploads/4/1/3/8/4138761/177290.jpg" class="galleryImage galleryImageBorder" _width="400" _height="121" style="position:absolute;border-width:1px;padding:6px;width:100%;top:29.85%;left:0%"></a></div></div></div></div><div id="999708087629570980-imageContainer20" style="float:left;width:33.28%;margin:0;"><div id="999708087629570980-insideImageContainer20" style="position:relative;margin:20px;padding:0 14px 14px 0"><div class="galleryImageHolder galleryCaptionHover" style="position:relative; width:100%; padding:0 0 75.08%;"><div class="galleryInnerImageHolder"><a href="/uploads/4/1/3/8/4138761/1242903_orig.jpg" rel="lightbox[gallery999708087629570980]" onclick="if (!window.lightboxLoaded) return false" title="Title: &quot;pano Mornington 2&quot;, Artist: Rob Mullner...Contact me for details" class="w-fancybox"><img src="/uploads/4/1/3/8/4138761/1242903.jpg" class="galleryImage galleryImageBorder" _width="400" _height="119" style="position:absolute;border-width:1px;padding:6px;width:100%;top:30.19%;left:0%"></a></div></div></div></div><div id="999708087629570980-imageContainer21" style="float:left;width:33.28%;margin:0;"><div id="999708087629570980-insideImageContainer21" style="position:relative;margin:20px;padding:0 14px 14px 0"><div class="galleryImageHolder galleryCaptionHover" style="position:relative; width:100%; padding:0 0 75.08%;"><div class="galleryInnerImageHolder"><a href="/uploads/4/1/3/8/4138761/5116176_orig.jpg" rel="lightbox[gallery999708087629570980]" onclick="if (!window.lightboxLoaded) return false" title="Title: &quot;Abstract&quot;, Artist: Paul Hoelen ...22 X 21.5 print...AUD $695" class="w-fancybox"><img src="/uploads/4/1/3/8/4138761/5116176.jpg" class="galleryImage galleryImageBorder" _width="400" _height="393" style="position:absolute;border-width:1px;padding:6px;width:76.41%;top:0%;left:11.79%"></a></div></div></div></div><div id="999708087629570980-imageContainer22" style="float:left;width:33.28%;margin:0;"><div id="999708087629570980-insideImageContainer22" style="position:relative;margin:20px;padding:0 14px 14px 0"><div class="galleryImageHolder galleryCaptionHover" style="position:relative; width:100%; padding:0 0 75.08%;"><div class="galleryInnerImageHolder"><a href="/uploads/4/1/3/8/4138761/46395_orig.jpg" rel="lightbox[gallery999708087629570980]" onclick="if (!window.lightboxLoaded) return false" title="Title: &quot;Abstract 2&quot;, Artist: Paul Hoelen ...30 X 20 print...AUD $595" class="w-fancybox"><img src="/uploads/4/1/3/8/4138761/46395.jpg" class="galleryImage galleryImageBorder" _width="400" _height="266" style="position:absolute;border-width:1px;padding:6px;width:100%;top:5.71%;left:0%"></a></div></div></div></div><span style="display: block; clear: both; height: 0px; overflow: hidden;"></span>
</div>
```

This from the website link you provided.

Copy Paste this code in your website using EMBED CODE. You should find a duplicate gallery appearing.

Then click on the code snippet and "Edit HTML Code"

This way you can edit public HTML, CSS(style tags) & Javascript(script tags) as the way you want.